# Installation error: Unknown failure

Tags: android

I just opened a new Android project thorugh eclipse, I want the application to run on my samsung galaxy s4 which has KitKat 4.4.2 on it, so I opened the project so as Target SDK is 5.0.1  and the compilation will be done with 4.4.2, just when the project opens I get errors, i fixed it by accesing both appcompat and the project`s project.properties and changing the target to apk-21. the errors vanish. But ! when I try to debug with my phone or with the emulator it fails, - Installation error: Unknown failure - that`s the error, as I looked through the web I saw many people that get through this problem and non of the solutions was posted solved my problem. I will be really glad if someone could help me solve this annoying thing. Thank! !

Comment: Please post the manifest.

Comment: Project`s Manifest- http://pastebin.com/T24DCWE3

Comment: Appcompat Manifest -http://pastebin.com/Y2vTp6YN

Comment: @sitoNz if you have previously installed it, then uninstall it and reinstall.

Comment: @Krupal if I previously installed what ? and I have installed eclipse and the whole sdk about a week ago

Comment: @sitoNz apk of your app

Comment: I can`t even instal it because of the error.

Comment: How do you have two manifests? Your appcompat manifest has `android:minSdkVersion="7"`, no `android:targetSdkVersion` at all, and lists no activities. That makes any APK built with it basically useless. I'm not surprised that installation fails with an undecipherable error. Set the `minSdkVersion` to the lowest Android version you actually expect to support in your app and set `targetSdkVersion` to the highest version you know your app is compatible with. Then add one or more `<activity>` tags as children of the `<application>` tag to declare your activity or activities.

Answer (score 7):

I had the similar kind of issue and I have resolved the issue following the steps below:

1. **File** >> **Settings** >> **Build**, **Execution**, **Deployment**.
2. Next click on **Instant Run** and uncheck "**Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy**".
3. **Apply** and **OK**.

Try building the app again now. It should work now. Enable the Instant Run feature again if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue in Android Nougat.

Reason happened to be renaming the Project Folder.

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Rebuild Project

Try this out in case you have altered anything related to Project Structure or Gradle Settings.

Answer (score 0):

It happened for me also. Try to unplug your device and reconnect again. Once done, run `adb devices` in your command prompt to see if the device is detected successfully.

If yes, then clean and run the project. This worked for me. Give it a try.

**Second Option**

Try to delete your debug certificate and then restart the eclipse. Do Project clean - build and run the application

Debug certificate path depends on platforms. Find it in

> Preferences - Android - Build - Default debug keystore.

Comment: The device is deteced successfully, I can see it in `Devices` tab. I also prompt to pick a device and I pick my device. The problem occursed also on my emulator not precisly on my personal device.

Comment: @sitoNz, Try my second option please

Comment: @sitoNz, traverse to the path in system and remove it